# SQLite trigger to increment a column value when a record is altered

Tags: sqlite, triggers, increment

I am in the process of coding a series of update queries that evaluate a table's records and make changes to one or more fields/columns when appropriate.

I need a way to track which records have been changed.  To this end I've historically used the following trigger to modify a field `sqlmodded` which then enabled me to export only changed records to a new table, the contents of which is then used to update metadata in underlying files.  The trigger is as follows:

```
/* old faithful trigger */
CREATE TRIGGER sqlmods
         AFTER UPDATE
            ON alib
      FOR EACH ROW
          WHEN old.sqlmodded IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE alib
       SET sqlmodded = TRUE
     WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

I'd like to go one step further and use `sqlmodded` for dual purposes by leveraging a single trigger that increments `sqlmodded`.  When all changes are processed the state of `sqlmodded` will signify the following:

- if `> 0` it denotes the number of changes to which the record has been subjected
- if `null` (or `0` if necessary to default to `0`) the record has not been altered

After much fiddling I've landed on the following, which does appear to work:

```
/* proposed trigger to signify change and number of changes processed */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS sqlmods
                       AFTER UPDATE
                          ON alib
                    FOR EACH ROW
                        WHEN old.sqlmodded IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE alib
       SET sqlmodded = iif(sqlmodded IS NULL, '1', (CAST (sqlmodded AS INTEGER) + 1) ) 
     WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

As the table in question contains hundreds of thousands or rows and many fields/columns against which many update queries are run I was wondering  whether there would be any significant performance improvement if I defined `sqlmodded` as `INTEGER` and defaulted its value to `0` or whether there is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having now utilised this trigger to process what in effect amounts to over 500k changes it works as intended and its performance is satisfactory, so no further optimisation comments required.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS sqlmods
                       AFTER UPDATE
                          ON alib
                    FOR EACH ROW
                        WHEN old.sqlmodded IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE alib
       SET sqlmodded = iif(sqlmodded IS NULL, '1', (CAST (sqlmodded AS INTEGER) + 1) ) 
     WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```